# Best way to test equivalency in two sql fields

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be the best way to test if two fields are the same in mysql? Currently I do the following, to take into effect the `NULL` case:

```
WHERE COALESCE(field1, '') = COALESCE(field2, '')
```

Or is there another shorter form of doing that equivalency check?

Comment: The `<=>` operator the answers refer to is MySQL-specific syntax. Standard SQL defines a predicate called `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`. Same purpose, just more SQL-like syntax with English words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in MySQL

The `<=>` (spaceship) operator.

In ANSI SQL

```
<column> IS NOT DISTINCT FROM <column>
```

or if above is not supported

```
CASE
 WHEN
    (<column> = <column>) OR (<column> IS NULL AND <column> IS NULL)
 THEN 1
 ELSE 0
END
```

**Some test queries and results**

```
**Query #1**

    SELECT 1 <=> 1 MySQL, CASE WHEN (1 = 1) OR (1 IS NULL and 1 IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ANSI_SQL;

| MySQL | ANSI_SQL |
| ----- | -------- |
| 1     | 1        |

---
**Query #2**

    SELECT 0 <=> 0 MySQL, CASE WHEN (0 = 0) OR (0 IS NULL and 0 IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ANSI_SQL;

| MySQL | ANSI_SQL |
| ----- | -------- |
| 1     | 1        |

---
**Query #3**

    SELECT 1 <=> NULL MySQL, CASE WHEN (1 = NULL) OR (1 IS NULL and NULL IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ANSI_SQL;

| MySQL | ANSI_SQL |
| ----- | -------- |
| 0     | 0        |

---
**Query #4**

    SELECT NULL <=> NULL MySQL, CASE WHEN (NULL = NULL) OR (NULL IS NULL and NULL IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ANSI_SQL;

| MySQL | ANSI_SQL |
| ----- | -------- |
| 1     | 1        |

---
**Query #5**

    SELECT 0 <=> NULL MySQL, CASE WHEN (0 = NULL) OR (0 IS NULL and NULL IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ANSI_SQL;

| MySQL | ANSI_SQL |
| ----- | -------- |
| 0     | 0        |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c8ySbedy7XcUCDyi4WLyeB/5) between the `<=> (MySQL)`  and the `CASE END (ANSI SQL)` method.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), the null-safe comparison:

```
where field1 <=> field2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE COALESCE(field1, '') = COALESCE(field2, '')
```

this cannot check equality since field1 can be `null` and field2 can be empty string (`''`).

you may use **null safe operator**

```
field1 <=> field2;
```